# Using JSONP API from forecast.io with WinJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

First off, apologies if this is a silly question, I'm new to WinJS and relatively new to Javascript, but I've been going great til I hit this roadblock.

I'm currently working on a weather app for Windows 8 using WinJS, and I'm trying to pull the data from the forecast.io API, which in my case is provided in JSONP format.
I easily got it working in-browser using jQuery and .getJSON, but since I have to use WinJS.xhr to request the data instead I'm having some difficulty.

I can pull the data just fine using the following code:

```
function getWeather() {
    WinJS.xhr({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/*ommited API key*/-36.044394,146.953718?callback=?&units=si",
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" }
    }).then(function complete(data) {
        var weatherData = data.responseText;
        (new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(weatherData, "Success!")).showAsync().done();
    }, function error(data) {
        (new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Failed.", "Error")).showAsync().done();
    });
}
```

This shows me the data in a popup window, so I'm sure that I've accessed it. The problem is, I can't do anything with it. In jQuery I simply used "data.currently.temperature" to get the current temperature data, but I can't get something similar working in this situation.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

P.S sorry if I butchered any terminology, I'm doing my best.

Here's what data.responseText returns, there's quite a lot so I put it in a text file.
http://justadddesign.net/data.responseText.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `data.responseText` is string not object. Try:

```
var forecastInfo = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
```

and then access `forecastInfo` object properties.

Comment: I can't, JSON.parse throws an error saying that there's an invalid character

Comment: share the data.responseText text from the debugger.

Comment: Added it to the original post

Comment: I see, just remove callback=? from url, so response will be returned as valid JSON. Same origin policy doesn't apply to winjs apps so you should be able to work without JSONP hack.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are my saviour :D